# Intercept (or force to stop) long press gesture recognizer in swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer, wkwebview

I used long press gesture recognizer to set my own wkwebview link actionsheet, however the actionsheet won't appear until I release my finger (I tried `recognizer.began` but it does not work...)

So, how can I intercept the long press recognizer? Can I add a timer to stop it? How?

P.s. here's are my code:

```
//long press to show the action sheet
        longPressRecognizer.delegate = self
        longPressRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: "onLongPress:")
        self.webView.scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRecognizer)

func onLongPress(gestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer){
        longPressSwitch = true
    }
```

Comment: Have you solved your issue and can you still remember how?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a long press recognizer, use an NSTimer. Here's a quick implementation example (Swift 2):

```
var sameTouch = false
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    _ = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.5, target: self, selector: "longPressed", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    sameTouch = true
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    sameTouch = false
}

func longPressed() {
    if(sameTouch) {
        longPressSwitch = true
        sameTouch = false
    }
}
```

Pretty simple stuff; when 'touch began', we start the timer which will run for 1.5 seconds. We say `_ = ...` because we will never reference that timer again, so naming it is unnecessary. We also set the variable `sameTouch` to true.

If touchesEnded, we set `sameTouch` to false. This is because that would indicate to `longPressed()` that the touch was released early.

In `longPressed()`, we set `longPressSwitch` to true--that's from your code. The line, `sameTouch = false` is not 100% necessary, but it illustrates the closure of the system in my eyes.

Hope, this helps! If you have questions, please, tell me!

Comment: Doesn't work, because Wkwebview cannot recognise touchesBegan & touchesEnded events...  and this is why I used UIGestureRecognizer.

Comment: @JasonHoncheungWong, are you using UIWebView or UIWebViewController?

Comment: I used WKWebView instead of UIWebView... still struggling of this issue...  or are there any method that could send a TouchUpInside event (make fake finger releasing signal) to the gesture recognizer?

Comment: @JasonHoncheungWong, if you want an action to run when touch is released, maybe add a UITapGestureRecognizer? If a UILongPressGestureRecognizer is being called, then a UITapGestureRecognizer should too as they are both subclasses of UIGestureRecognizer

Comment: UITapGestureRecognizer is not being called while wkwebview was implemented..  Can you please take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35499976/wkwebview-decidepolicyfornavigationaction-being-call-after-the-long-press-recogn) which I was stuck in... @Dopapp

Comment: @JasonHoncheungWong, so, just to be clear, do you want something to happen when a tap happens anywhere in the bounds of the web view, or do you want actions for links or something more specific like that?

Comment: I want actions for links. I want to get the links url address before the action sheet menu shows up.